# FFPlay: How to manually select video quality during playing the mpd stream?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, mpeg-dash, ffplay

I used ffplay to play mpd stream and successed,

Here the MPD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MPD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011 http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd"
    profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011"
    type="static"
    mediaPresentationDuration="PT1M8.7S"
    maxSegmentDuration="PT5.0S"
    minBufferTime="PT12.5S">
    <ProgramInformation>
    </ProgramInformation>
    <ServiceDescription id="0">
    </ServiceDescription>
    <Period id="0" start="PT0.0S">
        <AdaptationSet id="0" contentType="video" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" bitstreamSwitching="true" frameRate="24000/1001" maxWidth="1280" maxHeight="720" par="16:9">
        <Representation id="0" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.4d401f" bandwidth="10237" width="480" height="270" sar="1:1">
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="24000" initialization="init-stream$RepresentationID$.m4s" media="chunk-stream$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.m4s" startNumber="1">
                <SegmentTimeline>
                    <S t="0" d="150150" r="9" />
                    <S d="149149" />
                </SegmentTimeline>
            </SegmentTemplate>
        </Representation>
        <Representation id="2" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.4d401f" bandwidth="60882" width="1280" height="720" sar="1:1">
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="24000" initialization="init-stream$RepresentationID$.m4s" media="chunk-stream$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.m4s" startNumber="1">
                <SegmentTimeline>
                    <S t="0" d="150150" r="9" />
                    <S d="149149" />
                </SegmentTimeline>
            </SegmentTemplate>
        </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
    <AdaptationSet id="1" contentType="audio" startWithSAP="1" segmentAlignment="true" bitstreamSwitching="true" lang="und">
        <Representation id="1" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="128000" audioSamplingRate="32000">
            <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2" />
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="32000" initialization="init-stream$RepresentationID$.m4s" media="chunk-stream$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.m4s" startNumber="1">
                <SegmentTimeline>
                    <S t="0" d="159744" />
                    <S d="160768" r="11" />
                    <S d="111915" />
                </SegmentTimeline>
            </SegmentTemplate>
        </Representation>
        <Representation id="3" mimeType="audio/mp4" codecs="mp4a.40.2" bandwidth="128000" audioSamplingRate="44100">
            <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2" />
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="44100" initialization="init-stream$RepresentationID$.m4s" media="chunk-stream$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.m4s" startNumber="1">
                <SegmentTimeline>
                    <S t="0" d="220160" />
                    <S d="221184" r="11" />
                    <S d="158713" />
                </SegmentTimeline>
            </SegmentTemplate>
        </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
</Period>
```

this dash stream contains 2 vindeos(480P and 720P), and 2 audios.The videos always starts low quality(480P), I want to change the video resolution to the high quality(720P) during playing process, what should i do?

Comment: Why do you have the `c++`  tag? Do you expect an answer in C++? I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549399/ffmpeg-how-to-manually-select-video-quality-from-mpd-manifest), that uses FFprobe and FFmpeg. I think you can use FFprobe and FFplay the same way. In case you want something to select the best quality automatically I don't think C++ is the best choice.

Comment: I am getting an error: `"Unable to parse 'manifest.mpd' - missing root node"`. Are you sure your posted MPD is valid and complete?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549399/ffmpeg-how-to-manually-select-video-quality-from-mpd-manifest] is about the ffmpeg command , and it select stream before playing , i want to select stream during plaing with ffmpeg source code both C  or C++ is ok for me